# Swift 3.0: compare element row in a matrix

Tags: swift, swift3

I want compare all element in a row (in a matrix). In a rows or columns should be no equal numbers.

Like this

```
for i in matri{
  if (matrix[0][0] == matrix[0][1]{
    print ("error: equal number")
  }else{
  print ("OK")
 }
}
```

But this compare only first value with next index number. How I do solve this problem? I need to compare each row and each column

```
 1-1-3-6-4
```

Error:

```
1-3-4-5-6
1-5-3-9-4
```

Error

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a matrix

```
let matrix = [[1, 1, 3, 6, 4], [1, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 5, 3, 9, 4]]
```

you can find the rows with duplicates simply writing

```
let rowsWithDuplicates = matrix.filter { Set($0).count != $0.count }
```

and finally print the duplicates

```
for row in rowsWithDuplicates {
    print("Found a duplicate in \(row)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks and for print a error message after rowduplicates? And for check column?

Comment: @neo999 Just add `for row in rowsWithDuplicates { print("Found a duplicate in \(row)") }`

Comment: I write this: let rowsWithDuplicates = board.filter{     Set($0).count != $0.count     for row in rowsWithDuplicates{          print("Found duplicate in \(row)")     } } but not work (board is name if my Matrix)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that returns false if two equal numbers are found in the same row/column.

```
func test(matrix: [[Int]]) -> Bool {
    for (i, row) in matrix.enumerated() {
        for (j, value) in row.enumerated() {
            for (k, _value) in row.enumerated() where j != k {
                if _value == value {
                    return false
                }
            }
            for (l, _row) in matrix.enumerated() where l != i {
                if _row[j] == value {
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

This method will generate a random matrix with the dimensions given.

```
func generate(matrix m: Int, by n: Int) -> [[Int]] {

    var matrix = [[Int]]()

    for i in 0..<m {
        matrix.append([Int]())
        for _ in 0..<n {
            matrix[i].append(Int(arc4random_uniform(11)))
        }
    }

    return matrix
}
```

Lastly, this tests the validity of a given number of matrices and returns all the valid ones.

```
func valid(matrices count: Int, ofSize size: (Int, Int) -> [[[Int]]] {

    var matrices = [[[Int]]]()

    for _ in 0 ..< tries {
        let matrix = generate(matrix: size.0, by: size.1)
        if test(matrix: matrix) {
            matrices.append(matrix)
        }
    }

    return matrices
}
```

So finally, printing out the result will give us the all the valid random permutations generated.

```
print(valid(matrices: 100, ofSize: (5, 2)))

//  [
//      [
//          [2, 0],
//          [7, 8],
//          [3, 5],
//          [9, 1],
//          [4, 2]
//      ],
//      [
//          [9, 3],
//          [7, 8],
//          [5, 0],
//          [2, 5],
//          [6, 4]
//      ],
//      ...
//  ]
```